# Where do the frame overruns come from?

Tags: networking

I have a network setup like this:

```
   +------------------------+
   | Switch                 |
   |                        |
   +---------+-----+----+---+
             |     |    |
             |     |    |
 AP1 --------+     |    |
  |                |    +------- VDR (PC)
  |                |
 AP2               |
                   +------------ Laptop
```

AP1 is a Fritzbox. AP2 is a TP-Link TL-WA801N thats plugged directly into one of the fritzboxes ethernet ports (because the switch is full).

Recently, I detected many frame errors on eth0 of VDR:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e0:cb:4e:e0:d0:3c  
          inet addr:192.168.178.23  Bcast:192.168.178.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::e2cb:4eff:fee0:d03c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2069912 errors:76197 dropped:0 overruns:76197 frame:0
          TX packets:2002465 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:424918548 (424.9 MB)  TX bytes:609973494 (609.9 MB)
          Interrupt:41 Base address:0xe000
```

The number of frame errors and overruns stays stable until I start streaming video from VDR to the Laptop over wifi, using either one of the wifi access points. Then the number of frame errors and overruns starts rising constantly.

When I disable wifi and plug a patchcable into the NIC of the laptop, no errors happen.

This could be some standard networking problem, but unfortunately I have no clue about it :s

Maybe it's a bad patchcable between the fritzbox and the switch. I'll check this later, when I have a spare cable. **Update**: It was not the cable. Just changed it, no effect.

Could you please help me getting rid of the frame errors?